# dotnet core websites binding to same port in IIS Kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an application that contains multiple projects, all this works fine.  Now I need to upload this multiple times to different folders on our server.  Each folder is setup as a website, and each website has its own sub-application (website is the WEBSITE application, and sub-application is the API application)

I seem to be having problems whereby an application will start up and then close straight away.  After saving the log files to a text file, it appears that sometimes the websites startup on a PORT that is already being used on the server.

Is there a way to make sure 2 applications do not bind to the same PORT?  I know you can use the `.UseUrls` method against `WebHostBuilder` but I really do not want to have to keep a log of what each PORT each website is bound to, and would rather dotnet done this automatically.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

So couple of questions asked, about things which i may not have explained well, for this i am sorry, and hopefully here are some more details that will help.

In IIS my binding are simply to port 80 for each site, something like this.

[image]

As far as hosting goes i am using IIS, i have used the `dotnet publish` command on both my applications which contains all the dlls and exe files needed for my site.  I have uploading this into my website folder, as below

[image]

[image]

As you can see here, there are 2 log files from my application, both are under different websites in IIS, but you can see that kestrel is starting them up on the same port.

Application 1

```
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\inetpub\webroot\myapp1\api
Now listening on: http://localhost:33587
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://www.mydomain1.co.uk/api/connect/token application/x-www-form-urlencoded 848
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 20.0675ms 400 application/json;charset=UTF-8
Application is shutting down...
info: Hangfire.BackgroundJobServer[0]
      Hangfire Server stopped.
```

Application 2

```
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\inetpub\webroot\myapp2\api
Now listening on: http://localhost:33587
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://www.mydomain2.co.uk/api/connect/token application/x-www-form-urlencoded 848
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 20.0675ms 400 application/json;charset=UTF-8
Application is shutting down...
info: Hangfire.BackgroundJobServer[0]
      Hangfire Server stopped.
```

I have about 10 copies of this application under 10 different IIS websites using different domains the fix i have must be simple if possible.

More info, in my `Program.cs` i am using this code

```
var webhostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddConsole())
    .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddDebug())
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false)
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

**UPDATE 2**

To try and force each website to use a particular code, i have added a `UsePort` parameter in the `appsettings.json` file, where i have other settings and in my `Program.cs` file i have added this code.  It is not binding to the port at all! Am i doing this wrong?

```
// hosting
var webhostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddConsole())
    .ConfigureLogging(options => options.AddDebug())
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false)
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseUrls("http://localhost:" + appSettings.UsePort);
```

As you can see in the log, it is using a random port still, because i set it to 2018

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\inetpub\webroot\my-app1
Now listening on: http://localhost:6380
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Comment: What have you set as the bindings for the sites in IIS? This is controlled in IIS, not as part of ASP.NET Core.

Comment: You can set a random port of a range of usually free Ports in your program.cs, but this can cause issues, if one service tries to call another.

Comment: It's not clear if your trying to host your web apps in IIS or as stand alone executables... I know you can create a single website in IIS and then have multiple apps within it.

Comment: Updated with more details for you all :D

Comment: Do you have the IIS on your own server, or do you use Aws or something like that?

Comment: Did you find answer to this problem? I having the same issue as well.